# selecting k from n elements in mapreduce

Tags: algorithm, hadoop, hash, parallel-processing, mapreduce

Assume an input of `x` records, `n` of which having a desired property (e.g. their value is positive) and all `x` having a unique key.

**What I want to do is, using a map-only job in MapReduce, emit exactly `k` of these `n` records.**

For example, assume this is my input:

```
(a, 10)
(g, -3)
(c, -2)
(f, 4)
(s, 2)
```

and I want to emit exactly 2 elements with positive value. In this example `x` is 5, `n` is 3 and `k` is 2. I know `x` (which I think is not needed), `k` and `n` before the job starts.
The problem is that records with positive values could be processed by different mappers.

What I have thought of, is use a hashtable of size `n` in each mapper and use the hash of the key to put elements with positive value in this hashtable. Then, elements in the first `k` positions of the hashtable will be emitted. This would not work however, if two records fall in the same hash bucket. Any alternatives?

Comment: Do you mean that each mapper should emit `k` values, or that the whole job should emit `k` values? In the second case, I don't think it is possible to do it without a reducer, since each mapper should know how much positive values have the rest of the mappers emitted.

Comment: I mean latter: the whole job should emit `k` values.

Comment: Assuming a perfect hash function, I would expect this to work.

Comment: By the looks of your data, it is not possible to write a perfect hash function since the keys that have a positive value are completely random.

Comment: Why does it need to be a map-only job? Balduz is correct, you can't do that without a reducer (unless you go with your probabilistic hash, which might not yield exactly `k` values). You could use two map-only jobs however, if you are insisting to hack around.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut For efficiency reasons, so as to skip the shuffling & sorting overhead. `k` is in the order of tens of millions and `n` could be hundreds of millions. If I could skip this overhead, I would save some time. As for hashing, I agree, that's why I have this problem. Two map-only jobs, or maybe a ChainMapper seems like a good idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it with a map-only job and a bit of sequential code, it is quite hacky however and in most of the cases it is just simpler to use a reducer.

In a more formalized language you want to do a filter (sql where) and a select (sql limit). The filter can be parallelized, the select can't unless you want to go for a probabilistic approach.

The idea is the following:

1. In your map-only job you can filter your data according to your selection criterion.
2. You also track a meta information about how many records you have filtered in the mapper.
3. Write this number into a file in shared file system, I guess HDFS in your case. Name the file after the task id or output file name plus some suffix.

`3.` should yield a bunch of meta files in your file system that you can read, with their corresponding map outputs. Then just greedily read a new meta file until you have reached your `k`. In case you have more records in a map output / meta file, you can prune the output file (or tell whatever comes next that it only need to read `y` records from that "overflow" file).

Comment: If I get this correctly, would it be the same (in logic) as doing the following process:
1. Emit all `n` records from the map-only job
2. `hadoop -getmerge`
3. use `head -k` unix command to get the desired output?

Comment: @vefthym `getmerge` is touching the "big" output files and rewriting them completely. You only choose the output files in a smarter way. I don't know about your output requirements.

Comment: Not exactly what I was wishing, but this is indeed a correct answer to my problem. Thanks Thomas!